# How to read a file line by line with space separated values?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a different kind of file format which contains millions of lines in a txt file.

My file format is something like this:

```
12122.AA.K IRIR-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,6373,893939,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
12123.AA.K KKKS-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9393,039033,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
12122.AA.K PEOEP-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9033,930392,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
12124.AA.K MDJDK-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,3930,272882,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
12125.AA.K EOEPE-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,8393,039393,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
```

In Python, I want to split each line into a key and a value:

```
Key: 12122.AA.K
Value: IRIR-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,3833,343343,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
```

As you can see, the key and value are differentiated by one empty space only.

What's the efficient way of getting in python?

Comment: what have you tried so far and why isn't that working?

Comment: Try method [split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). By default, it splits strings on whitespace

Comment: @learnjquery: Well, in the update, lines 1 and 3 have the same key, different values. So how do you handle that? Keep first, keep last, keep collection of all values?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    mapping = dict(line.split(' ', 1) for line in f)
```

Comment: Note: This will error if any line lacks a space character. If you want to handle such lines by pairing a key (the contents of the line) with the empty string, you can do: `dict(line.partition(' ')[::2] for line in f)`. `partition` always returns exactly three values, so taking even index values always gets you exactly two (the middle value is the partition character if found, which you don't care about here).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as file:
   thedict={e.split(' ')[0]:e.split(' ')[1] for e in file}
```

You could try this dictionary comprehension

Comment: @schwobaseggl is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I was just amused by the bare dict with millions of items. The initial read and split was not ideal, now I like it better. Still calling split twice feels unnecessary. See the other answer which avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be overkill, but you can also use the built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

While it's designed to work for comma-separated values by default, it does provide a way to [register a custom dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.register_dialect) to match custom file formats, such as files with space-separated values. The [Dialect and Formatting Parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) includes an attribute for a [`delimiter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) which you can set to a space `" "`.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

csv.register_dialect("my_custom_dialect", delimiter=" ")

mapping1 = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect="my_custom_dialect")
    for row in reader:
        # Each row is a list of strings separated by the delimiter
        key, value = row
        mapping1[key] = value
pprint(mapping1)
```

```
{'12122.AA.K': 'IRIR-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,6373,893939,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393',
 '12123.AA.K': 'KKKS-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9393,039033,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393',
 '12124.AA.K': 'PEOEP-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9033,930392,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393',
 '12125.AA.K': 'MDJDK-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,3930,272882,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393',
 '12126.AA.K': 'EOEPE-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,8393,039393,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393'}
```

If your file has headers, then you can leverage `csv`'s [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to access each row's values as a dict.

```
KEY VALUE
12122.AA.K IRIR-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,6373,893939,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
12123.AA.K KKKS-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9393,039033,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
12124.AA.K PEOEP-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9033,930392,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393
```

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

csv.register_dialect("my_custom_dialect", delimiter=" ")

mapping2 = {}
with open("test_with_headers.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect="my_custom_dialect")
    for row in reader:
        # 'row' is a dictionary with the headers as the key
        mapping2[row["KEY"]] = row["VALUE"]
pprint(mapping2)
```

```
{'12122.AA.K': 'IRIR-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,6373,893939,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393',
 '12123.AA.K': 'KKKS-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9393,039033,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393',
 '12124.AA.K': 'PEOEP-93I3KD-OEPE-IE,9033,930392,09/12/2093,,N,EC,3838-38939-393'}
```