# How do I read lines from a file and create a dictionary from them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a file that contains 2 letters on each line separated by white space for example:

```
a  b
c  d
e   f
```

How can I create a function that reads this and turns it into a dictionary where the first letter of each line is the key and the second letter of each line is the value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line by line with space separated values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086002/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-with-space-separated-values-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code first reads the file line by line and then splits each line into a 2d array so it looks like this:

```
[[a, b],
 [c, d]
 ...
       ]
```

It adds dictionary entries based on this array (mydict[a] = b and so on).

```
with open("filename", "r") as file:
    myinput = file.readlines()
myinput = [i.split(" ") for i in myinput]
mydict = {}
for i in myinput:
    mydict[i[0]] = i[1]
```

As @wjandrea pointed out, you can also write the above code like this:

```
with open("filename", "r") as file:
    mydict = {line.split() for line in file}
```

Comment: `input` is a bad variable name since it shadows the builtin `input()`

Comment: Why do you do it in four steps when you can do it in one? `mydict = {line.split() for line in file}`

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for your suggestions! I've edited my answer to include them.