# Which index of string is an int in python

Tags: python, file

I am reading a text file with high scores and trying to find which index of the string is where the name stops, and the score starts. This is the format of the file:

```
John 15
bob 27
mary 72
videogameplayer99 99
guest 71
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Just use `line.split()` split it into the name and score.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line by line with space separated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086002/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-with-space-separated-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find the index to split the string into 2 separate parts, then you can just use `[string].split()` (where `string` is an individual line). If you need to find the index of the space for some other reason, use: `[string].index(" ")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the line to separate it by the space. It will result in a list containing the 2 'words' in the line, in this case the words will be the name and the score (in string). You can get it using:

```
result = line.split()
name = result[0]
score = int(result[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, for each line, you would be looking for the index where you first find the space character `" "`. In python, you can accomplish this by using the `find` function on a string. For example, if you have a string `s = videogameplayer99 99`, then `s.find(" ")` will return `17'.

If you are using this method to split a name from a number, I would instead recommend using the `split` function, which will split a string based on some delimiter character. For example, `s.split(" ") = ["videogameplayer99", "99"]`.